# join() method misunderstanding

Tags: python

I've recently being doing online programming challenges. The prompt goes like this:

> Given a string now being a timestamp in the format hh:mm:ss, and three integers hrs, mins and sec being the hours, minutes and seconds to add, implement a function that returns a string being the newly adjusted timestamp (maintaining the same format).

My solution is as follows

```
def time_adjust(now,hrs,mins,sec):
  current = [int(i) for i in now.split(":")]
  values = [hrs,mins,sec]
  limit = (24,60,60)
  for i in range(0,3):
    current[i] = current[i] + values[i]
    if current[i]>limit[i]:
      current[i]-=limit[i]
    current[i] = str(current[i])
  seperator = ':'
  print(current)
  return(seperator.join(str(current)))
print(time_adjust("5:10:10",10,10,10))
```

However, when I run this program, it outputs

```
[:':1:5:':,: :':2:0:':,: :':2:0:':]
```

instead of the desirable

```
"15:20:20"
```

Could someone explain to me why this is?

Comment: What is `str(current)`?

Comment: yes, `str(current)` why are you doing that? That converts a list to a string. Now, you can `separator.join(some_string)`, but that isn't what you mean

Answer (score 3):

You're converting the list to string before joining. This is joining all the characters in the string.

Just join the list elements:

```
def time_adjust(now,hrs,mins,sec):
    current = [int(i) for i in now.split(":")]
    values = [hrs,mins,sec]
    limit = (24,60,60)
    for i in range(0,3):
      current[i] = current[i] + values[i]
      if current[i]>limit[i]:
        current[i]-=limit[i]
      current[i] = str(current[i])
    seperator = ':'
    print(current)
    return(seperator.join(current))
print(time_adjust("5:10:10",10,10,10))
```

Output

```
['15', '20', '20']
15:20:20
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it -

Issue is with your `str(current)`. Join works on a list of strings, and the `str(current)` results in a single string made from the list instead of a list. So it considers it as an iterable and puts the separate after each character.

```
def time_adjust(now,hrs,mins,sec):
    current = [int(i) for i in now.split(":")]
    values = [hrs,mins,sec]
    limit = (24,60,60)
    for i in range(0,3):
        current[i] = current[i] + values[i]
        if current[i]>limit[i]:
            current[i]-=limit[i]
            current[i] = str(current[i])
        seperator = ':'
    print(current)
    return(seperator.join([str(i) for i in current]))


print(time_adjust("5:10:10",10,10,10))
```

```
[15, 20, 20]
15:20:20
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that Python is trying to join together a string, not a list because you did `str(current)`.

try

```
def time_adjust(now,hrs,mins,sec):
      current = [int(i) for i in now.split(":")]
      values = [hrs,mins,sec]
      limit = (24,60,60)
      for i in range(0,3):
        current[i] = current[i] + values[i]
        if current[i]>limit[i]:
          current[i]-=limit[i]
        current[i] = str(current[i])
      seperator = ':'
      print(current)
      return(seperator.join(current))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you do `current[i] = str(current[i])`, so the elements of current are str and can be joined, seperated by that separator. So you do not need to convert the whole list of current to str.
`return(seperator.join(current))` will work.
Some other problems with your code:
You need to consider overflow case. This should be if `current[i] >= limit[i]`
then increment the higher order. So you should start adding seconds first, then minutes then hours, so the loop should be in reverse. Whole code:

```
def time_adjust(now,hrs,mins,sec):

    current = [int(i) for i in now.split(":")]
    values = [hrs,mins,sec]
    limit = (24,60,60)
    for i in range(2,-1,-1):
      current[i] = current[i] + values[i]
      if current[i]>=limit[i]:
        current[i]-=limit[i]
        if i!=0:
          current[i-1] += 1
      current[i] = str(current[i])

    seperator = ':'
    print(current)
    return(seperator.join(current))
  
print(time_adjust("5:10:10",10,10,50))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added some comments:

```py
def time_adjust(now, hrs, minutes, sec):
    current = [int(i) for i in now.split(":")]
    values = [hrs, minutes, sec]
    limit = (24, 60, 60)

    # In reverse order so that seconds are
    # added first, then minutes, and then hours
    for i in range(2, -1, -1):
        current[i] = current[i] + values[i]
        if current[i] > limit[i]:
            current[i] -= limit[i]

            # There is no place for days. So
            # just ignore the 24 hours
            if i - 1 >= 0:
                current[i - 1] += 1

    # Instead of converting the values to string
    # in the loop, we can do it here as well. I prefer
    # this because this way, we are not changing types
    # of existing variable from List[int] to List[str]
    # and it helps in debugging
    return ':'.join(map(str, current))


print(time_adjust("5:10:10", 10, 100, 10))
```